# Como hacer una función para validar si un dato existe o no en ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

estoy queriendo hacer que una función me valide si un dato que le pase existe en mi tabla o no, eh intentado con EXISTS y con COUNT() pero todavia no le agarro bien la mano para que funcione mi consulta:

```
    create or replace function fn_Validar(job_recibido employees.JOB_ID%TYPE)
    return employees.JOB_ID%TYPE
    IS
    
    validar employees.JOB_ID%TYPE;
    
    BEGIN
    
        if ((COUNT(*) from hr.employees WHERE JOB_ID = job_recibido) > 1)
         then
         validar := 'TRUE';
         
        ELSE 
         validar := 'FALSE';
        
        END IF;
        
        RETURN validar;
    END;
```

Ésta es una de las formas que traté de resolver éste ejercicio pero solamente consigo que me tire error:

**Errors**: FUNCTION FN_VALIDA
Line/Col: 8/18 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of the following:
) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
<an exponent (*.*)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec as between || multiset member submultiset
Line/Col: 8/66 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
. ( * @ % & - + ; / at mod remainder rem return returning
<an exponent (*.*)> and or || multiset

Alguna ayuda o recomendación que me puedan dar para poder resolverlo?

Muchas gracias

**EDIT:**

usando SELECT antes del COUNT() me tira el siguiente error:

**Error:** Line/Col: 9/14 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:( - + case mod new not null    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
date 
  pipe

Otra forma de probarlo fue:

```
create or replace function fn_Valida_Job(job_id_recibido hr.employees.JOB_ID%TYPE)
return hr.employees.JOB_ID%TYPE
IS

validar hr.employees.JOB_ID%TYPE;
cantidad number := 0;

BEGIN
    select COUNT(*) INTO cantidad
    from hr.employees WHERE JOB_ID = job_id_recibido

    if cantidad > 0 then 
        validar := 'TRUE';
        
    ELSE
        validar := 'FALSE';
    
    END IF;
    
    RETURN validar;
END;
```

pero con el siguiente error:

Errors: FUNCTION FN_VALIDA_JOB
Line/Col: 9/5 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 12/5 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Line/Col: 15/5 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE" when expecting one of the following:

( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
 
 << continue close current delete fetch lock
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query
json_object json_array

Line/Col: 20/5 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RETURN"

Comment: te falta el select.. if( select count(*) from...

Comment: Con el select tambien me estaba dando error, por eso lo saqué

Comment: pone el error que te daba con el select... igual ahora que lo pienso.. deberias pasar el count a una variable y luego controlar esa variable...

Comment: Si, estoy tratando de editarlo pero el stackOverflow me tira error, pero en eso estoy

Comment: saca el select del if.. pasa el count(*) a una variable y controla esa variable en el if...

Comment: cantidad number := 0;

BEGIN
    select COUNT(*) INTO cantidad
    from hr.employees WHERE JOB_ID = job_id_recibido asi? Y luego abro el IF

Comment: sipi.. lo probaste???

Comment: el if no lleva begin y end tambien? la query no debe termninar con ;???

Comment: Me faltaban los ; jaja

Comment: No olvides aceptar la respuesta que te ha sido útil, y de _explicar_ cómo la consulta resolvió tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a @gbianchi lo pude resolver

```
create or replace function fn_Valida_Job(job_id_recibido hr.employees.JOB_ID%TYPE)
return hr.employees.JOB_ID%TYPE
IS

validar hr.employees.JOB_ID%TYPE;
cantidad number := 0;

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cantidad
    from hr.employees WHERE JOB_ID = job_id_recibido;

    if cantidad > 0 then 
        validar := 'TRUE';
        
    ELSE
        validar := 'FALSE';
    
    END IF;
    
    RETURN validar;
END;
```

Comment: Por favor, pone una respuesa correcta, explicando cada problema y porque eran un problema.. y como se soluciona...

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo realice mediante un disparador que cada vez que intento ingresar un dato duplicado este lo elimina automáticamente espero te sirva

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TGR_ELIMINAR_DUPLICADO_FABRICANTES
```

AFTER INSERT
ON CM_FABRICANTES
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old

BEGIN
IF INSERTING() THEN

```
  DELETE FROM CM_FABRICANTES WHERE FABRICANTE_ID =(SELECT MAX(fabricante_id) FROM CM_FABRICANTES GROUP BY UPPER(FAB_DESCRIPCION)  HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

END IF ;

END TGR_ELIMINAR_DUPLICADO_FABRICANTES;